# Android getMaxEms() equivalent

Tags: android, xml, textview, ems

My TextView has `android:maxLines="1"` and I am getting an input from another EditText and pass it into the TextView . The problem is that when the first word of the input is too long the TextView doesn't show anything.So I want it to show the first part of the word and then end with "...". I have tried this

```
    int maxEms = textName.getMaxEms();
    if (setName.length() >maxEms){
        String str= "";
        for (int i=0;i<maxEms-3;i++){
            str+=setName.charAt(i);
        }
        str += "...";   
        textName.setText(str);
    }else textName.setText(setName);
```

but Eclipse says that .getMaxEms() requires Android API level 16

```
   <TextView
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:id="@+id/textSetName1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height= "match_parent"
        android:textSize = "17sp"/>
```

Comment: How are you setting the `maxEms` for that `TextView`?

Comment: I dont set the `android:maxEms` , so it depends on the screen width I guess

Comment: No, `maxEms` will not be set automatically for you. That's, `getMaxEms()` will return `-1` if you are not setting `maxEms` explicitly.

Comment: Did you try to set ellipsize instead? Add `android:ellipsize="end"` to your `TextView` and see what happens.

Comment: @shoerat nothing changed . The textView shows nothing when I enter a long phrase

Comment: Can you post your xml file?

Comment: I have edited the question , you can see it above

Comment: `android:ellipsize="end"` is working just as it should with `textName.setText("ThisIsASuperMegaUltraGrandKingLengthLongText");` You must be doing something else that's causing the error?

Comment: android:visibility="gone" , is present there .

Comment: I know about it ,, it turns into Visible during the program . 
android:ellipsize="end" works fine . Thanks @shoerat , Maybe I have done smth wrong on the first time

Comment: i am just a viewer but you are the Hero of your Question !